# Deserialize JSON response using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a web service which return response in JSON format as below.

> {"123":{"Name":"Abcd", "Age":"30"},"231":{"Name":"xyz", "Age":"20"}, "543":{"Name":"pqr", "Age":"35"}}

I want to deserialize this response in C# and wants to display it.

How can I do with Newtonsoft.Json library.

Please help me.

Comment: Couldn't you have looked at the documentation and tried to come up with something?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that "123", "231", and "543" are identifiers and not constant property names. In that case what you have is a dictionary of objects. First, define a class that maps to the object.

```
public class Something
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize into a dictionary of those objects.

```
var whatever = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Something>>(json);
```